# Return partial object from HQL query

Tags: java, rest, hql

I am building a simple weather app and in the api call I have query params where I can define what sensors to include and what weather data properties to include. When I have the query like `SELECT w FROM WeatherData w ...` the api response shows the key value pairs

[image]

But if I do a query like `SELECT w.temperature, w.humidity FROM WeatherData w ...` it just displays the values and not the properties.

[image]

How can I have it that the response includes the keys `temperature` and `humidity`? It's not just those, I could query to have just the `temperature`. But how do I include the keys in the response?

**Entity**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "WeatherData")
@Table(name = "weatherdata")
public class WeatherData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private float temperature;

    private float humidity;

    @Column(name = "wind_speed")
    private float windSpeed;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sensor_id")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Weather data needs to be linked to a sensor")
    private Sensor sensor;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

}
```

**Controller**

```
@Path("/weather")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class WeatherDataController {

    @Inject
    WeatherDataService service;

    @POST
    public Response postWeatherData(@NotNull @Valid WeatherData weatherData) {
        WeatherData createdWeatherData = service.saveWeatherData(weatherData);
        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                .entity(createdWeatherData)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{weatherDataId}")
    public Response getSpecificWeatherData(@PathParam("weatherDataId") Long weatherDataId) {
        WeatherData data = service.getWeatherDataById(weatherDataId);
        return Response
                .ok(data)
                .build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response getWeatherData(
            @QueryParam("sensor") List<String> sensorIds,
            @QueryParam("metric") List<String> metric,
            @QueryParam("statistic") String statistic,
            @QueryParam("dateStart") String dateStart,
            @QueryParam("dateEnd") String dateEnd
    ) throws Exception {
        ObjectNode response = service.getWeatherData(sensorIds, metric, Statistics.valueOf(statistic.toUpperCase()), dateStart, dateEnd);
        return Response
                .ok(response)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you attach, please, also your `dto` & `entity` in your question? It'd be informative in addition to provided images.

Comment: Could you show me, please, your controller class?

Comment: You need to create separately `dto` class with fields `temperature` and `humidity` besides `enity` in order to display fields as per your requirements in `Postman`. 

To clarify a bit:

`Entity` is related to `database`, and `dto` for displaying in Postman.

Comment: So if I wanted to have a query that just returns 'temperature', do I need to create a separate DTO that will just display the temp? Then if I wanted to query the `temperature` and `humidity`, would that be another DTO?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you want to display separated fields as `temperature` and `humidity` in `Postman`, you need to create `DTO` class. Also you can add `@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)` as mentioned in the [example](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields#on-class).

Comment: Nice, thanks for that, will give it a shot

Comment: Yes, sure, no problem. Also I'll add some points it could be helpful also for your future work: 
1) Instead of returning the object `Response` in endoints as a working solution, you can also return list of objects in endpoint;
2) You can return `dto` instead of entity as in the result;
3) And your service `service.getWeatherDataById` should return `dto`;
4) Also you can create the object as `RequestFilter` and put in the object all parameters. The object can contain all parameters inside.
5) `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`
`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` 
work in-built.

Comment: Also it'd be informative if you show your `getWestherData()` method in service and `ObjectNode` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not select certain values if you want to see full datasets.

If you need certain Key Value Sets returned you should probably edit your API Endpoint accordingly. Maybe you can build a new Entity Type that your Endpoint can return.

Comment: But I want to have the option to select multiple/single values